# Is iphone 5 apps scale down on ipad mini retina display?

Tags: ios

Can i test my iphone 5 apps on ipad mini retina with 4 inch screen?
I heard that iphone 5 apps scale down to 3.5 inch screen in ipad mini retina.
is it true?

Answer (score 1):

They're not scaled down. They're displayed in their original resolution, which is obviously less than the iPad Mini Retina resolution.